# How to authenticate in a SharePoint 2013 Mobile App

Tags: authentication, mobile

I am developing a mobile app and need to authenticate SharePoint 2013 from mobile app for the content.

How can this be implemented ?(without having to send the username and password with each request,looking for solutions that would not involve Azure ACS).

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has launched new Office 356 API which can be used for Authentication.

Please check the below links, it will surely help you authenticating SharePoint from Mobile Apps without using the Azure ACS service, Although you will need to Azure to register the App so Azure Active Directory is used to authenticate and authorize users.

- [Office 365 API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)
- [Add Storage to Your Apps with Office 365](http://blog.xamarin.com/add-storage-to-your-apps-with-office-365/)

This is the code

```
 public static readonly string DiscoveryServiceResourceId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
    public const string Authority = "https://login.windows.net/common";
    public static readonly Uri DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri =
    new Uri("https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/");
    public static Uri returnUri = new Uri(ProvideUrlHere);
    public static string clientId = ""; // Client ID generated from Azure
    public static AuthenticationContext authContext = null;
    public static string SharePointURL = ""; // SharePoint Url
 public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessToken(string serviceResourceId, PlatformParameters param)
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(serviceResourceId, clientId, returnUri, param);
        return authResult;
    }
```